# Why svchost suchost is running in cmd mode but not in taskmanager

Tags: command-line, hosts

If we go to task manager and check, there seems to be no svchost/suchost process running.
However, if we check in cmd mode, using the command `TASKLIST`, it shows a list of hosts that are running svc/suchost.

Answer (score 0):

Press the highlighted button and see:

[image: 1]

Comment: BTW, suchost.exe is malware. If you see it your PC's infected.

Answer (score 0):

Tasklist retrieves a list of processes running on a system. This commands do not permit you to change process state.

Whereas, task manager allows you to make changes to process properties - example, change its priority or even terminate it. You can change perform most operations on processes running under your user account.

Svchost does not run under your logged in account. It runs under a service account. I've noticed that the task manager interface does not list processes running the Local Service and Network Service account unless you run it as administrator.

More info

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/what-is-svchost-exe